# extend jquery-ui-datepicker with a new option

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Need your help here.

I'm trying to figure out how to properly extend datepicker with new option. For example I want the "setDate" option.

**Here how should it look like:**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  setDate: function(){
    return new Date().getTime(); // or any timestamp value
  }
});
```

As a result my **datepicker should be initialized this date value by default.**

I know that I simply can do:

```
var curr_date = new Date().getTime();
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', curr_date);
```

But **what I really want is to extend** a datepicker with a custom option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733904/how-can-i-extend-jqueryui-datepicker-to-accept-an-additional-argument)? It seems that could be useful to your cause.