# extend/catch all jQuery UI datepicker instances

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Since jQuery UI datepicker does not use the widget factory, and it's events are sparse.

I need to catch every datepicker open (beforeShow) and each onClose. I'd like to do this without needing to specify every instance individually.

Is there a method to do this effectively?

With UI dialog, I can catch all:

```
$(document).on("dialogopen", ".ui-dialog", function (event, ui) {
```

or extend:

```
var _open = $.ui.dialog.prototype.open;
$.ui.dialog.prototype.open = function() {
    var self = this;

    // apply original arguments
    _open.apply(this, arguments);
```

I haven't found a way to achieve this with datepicker. Ideas?

**EDIT:**

Found this:

```
var __picker = $.fn.datepicker;

$.fn.datepicker = function(options) {
    __picker.apply(this, [options]);
    var $self = this;
    console.log(options);
}
```

However, I actually need to override or set specific options for all datepickers.

Dialog example:

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype.options.modal = false;
```

**EDIT #2**

set dedault options,but still has to execute prior to any datepicker inits.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ closeText: 'close' })
```

Comment: Datepicker doesn't add some sort of class to its elements?

Comment: @Scimonster: Yup, it does. But then of course, you have to look things up individually, after the datepicker has been applied to the elements, rather than with delegation as in Jason's dialog example.

Comment: @Scimonster It's a terrible widget. The time things, it does well, but everything else is terrible. Lack of events, etc.

Comment: Seems you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7734037/335514 , but needs to be executed before datepicker initializes.