# Unable to manually open Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am trying to open jquery datepicker manually (**only on a custom button click event. The datepicker should not launch on selecting textbox**), but it is not working.

Am I missing anything?

```js
$(function() {
    $('#InputExpirationDateBtn').on('click', function () {
            $('#InputExpirationDateTxtBox').datepicker("show");
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch Test modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Test</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-sm-8">                                        
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Expiration Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputExpirationDateTxtBox" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="InputExpirationDateBtn" title="Click here to select Certification expiration date"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**Expectation**

Datepicker should be displayed only on the button click event and the selected value should get populated in the nearby textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

The z-index needs to be set

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
    z-index:1151 !important;
}
```

The datepicker needs to be defined before the click

```
$("#InputExpirationDateTxtBox").datepicker({
    showOn:'none' //making the datapicker show on nothing
});
```

Here is it working for you. https://jsfiddle.net/z39q8wff/2/

Just so you know. There is also an alternative [How can I extend jQueryUI datepicker to accept an additional argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733904/how-can-i-extend-jqueryui-datepicker-to-accept-an-additional-argument)

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be your custom button, because in jQuery datepicker you can specify how popup is invoked. If you set `showOn:button`, the button will be inserted beside the textbox and you can change button's caption or image.

```
  $("#InputExpirationDateTxtBox").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>'
  });
```