# jQuery-ui datepicker not working after extending to add placeholder

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to use the dateFormat property as a placeholder. I have extended the jQuery function but can not get it to work after extending demo in fiddle below. What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/yzk1avan/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datePicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        placeholder: true
    });
});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.datepicker = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.datepicker, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            if (settings.placeholder === true) {
                var dateFormat = settings.dateFormat;
                var placeholder = dateFormat.replace(/y/gi, 'yy');
                $(this).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
            }
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/yzk1avan/3/

Found my answer from here: [How can I extend jQueryUI datepicker to accept an additional argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733904/how-can-i-extend-jqueryui-datepicker-to-accept-an-additional-argument)

was missing these pieces of code:

var __picker = $.fn.datepicker;

__picker.apply(this, [options]);

Here's the working code:

```
var __picker = $.fn.datepicker;

(function($) {
$.fn.datepicker = function(options) {

     __picker.apply(this, [options]);

    var settings = $.extend({}, options);
    return this.each(function() {
    if (settings.placeholder === true) {
        var dateFormat = settings.dateFormat;
        var placeholder = dateFormat.replace(/y/gi, 'yy');
        $(this).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
    }
    });
}
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datePicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        placeholder: true
    });
});
```